# Sum of coprime divisors

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, optimization, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Define the following function to be the count of integers not greater than $L$ that are coprime to $n$:$$C(n,L)=\sum_{k=1 \atop {GCD(n,k)=1}}^L1$$

Then I am interested in the following sum:
$$S(x)=\sum_{d=1}^xd\cdot C(d,\Big\lfloor\frac xd \Big\rfloor)$$

$C$ can be calculated relatively fast given the prime factorization of $n$, which is assumed to be given in this question. But how can I reduce the time complexity of $S(x)$, to less than $O(x)$? I assume it can be achieved because the floor function takes $O(\sqrt x)$ different values, but the term in floor isn't the only parameter of the $C$ function, so it cannot be done trivially. Apparently, $S(x) = $ [A064609](https://oeis.org/A064609) in OEIS.

Some example values:

$C(504,10^6)=285715$

$S(10^5)=6842185902 \approx \frac {\pi^2\cdot10^{10}}{12\cdot\zeta(3)} $

Is there a way to do it? Or perhaps the entire sum can be transformed into something different altogether which admits a sublinear summation?

Comment: Where does that question come from? Looks suspiciously like Euler project.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's just a variation to the well known sum of divisors summatory function, $\sum_{n=1}^x \sigma_1(n)$. Only here I consider just the unitary divisors. I ask it completely unrelated, although it may appear in some PE problem I'm not aware of.